# Switching theme to RTL

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem. I'm trying to convert my Shopify theme to RTL from LTR, it's going well but the menu on mobile version make me the problem.

Basiclly, I added 
body { direction: rtl; } to my css files and change float: left to right.

What can I do with the menu? (see the white space)
Thanks [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjQuW.jpg)

Comment: maybe you just need to use css to adjust?

Comment: Maybe you should change all occurrences of "left" to 
"right" and vice versa.